# DIV Drawing Duplication And Priority

Tags: javascript, html, css, duplicates, z-index

I have a jsfiddle I'm working on `here`: https://jsfiddle.net/laroy/f9dhrrgg/

as you can see, there is a 3D column type image that I've created. I would like to duplicate this, and move the duplication to the right and on top of the original, such that they are overlapping. I've tried figuring it out but haven't been able to, so any help would be appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```css
.ultra {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sub_ultra {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 5em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right_side {
  height: 390px;
  width: 177px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 10em;
  margin-top: -7em;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.bottom_side {
  height: 380px;
  width: 142px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 7.1em;
  margin-top: -6.8em;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ultra">
  <div class="sub_ultra"></div>
</div>

<div class="right_side"></div>
<div class="bottom_side"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by wrapping your image in a relatively positioned container and using jQuery clone to create another copy.

[jQuery Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9dhrrgg/2/)

[No jQuery Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9dhrrgg/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <div class="ultra">
      <div class="sub_ultra"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_side"></div>
    <div class="bottom_side"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".image-wrap").clone().appendTo(".container").addClass("shifted")
```

Js (No jQuery)

```
var node = document.querySelector(".image-wrap").cloneNode(true);
node.className = node.className + " shifted";
document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(node);
```

New Css

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.shifted {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

Comment: I can get this to work in the fiddle but when I apply it to the site I'm building it doesn't do anything... any ideas why that might be? Maybe I'm including the JS incorrectly.

Comment: within the script tags, which look like this --> <script type="text/javascript"></script> I have the following --> $(".image-wrap").clone().appendTo(".container").addClass("shifted"); and its telling me that it 'Can't find variable "$" '

Comment: Then you probably aren't using jQuery. Use the js code marked No jQuery. You can ignore the code in the jQuery block.

Comment: I'm using the No jQuery solution now, but it is placing the clone right beneath the original. In the " shifted" part of the solution, the space was blocking it, but now, without the space, it has the class of image-wrapshifted...

Comment: You really need the space between your class names. `" shifted" ` is correct. What do you mean the space was blocking it?